# comparing two fields that may be null

Tags: postgresql

Is there a comparison operator where a.unitnum = b.unitnum would be `true` if both a.unitnum and b.unitnum are null? Seems that a.unitnum IS b.unitnum is invalid

Answer (score 39, accepted):

yes, there is [`IS DISTINCT FROM` and `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html)

```
postgres=# \pset null ****
Null display is "****".
postgres=# select null = null;
┌──────────┐
│ ?column? │
╞══════════╡
│ ****     │
└──────────┘
(1 row)

postgres=# select null is not distinct from null;
┌──────────┐
│ ?column? │
╞══════════╡
│ t        │
└──────────┘
(1 row)

postgres=# select 10 = null;
┌──────────┐
│ ?column? │
╞══════════╡
│ ****     │
└──────────┘
(1 row)

postgres=# select 10 is distinct from null;
┌──────────┐
│ ?column? │
╞══════════╡
│ t        │
└──────────┘
(1 row)

postgres=# select 10 is not distinct from null;
┌──────────┐
│ ?column? │
╞══════════╡
│ f        │
└──────────┘
(1 row)

postgres=# select 10 is not distinct from 20;
┌──────────┐
│ ?column? │
╞══════════╡
│ f        │
└──────────┘
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 3):

yes, [there is](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-compatible.html), but [it is recomended to not use it](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html). here is sample:

```
t=# select null = null;
 ?column?
----------

(1 row)

t=# set transform_null_equals = on;
SET
t=# select null = null;
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

**UPDATE:** apparently would work only for comparison `column = NULL`, not column = column:

```
t=# with s as (select null::int a, null::int b) select a <> b from s;
 ?column?
----------

(1 row)
```

so the shortest comparison would be coalesce:

```
t=# with s as (select null::int a, null::int b) select coalesce(a,b,0) = 0 from s;
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Comment: kha! it does not compare two columns :)

Comment: I get COALESCE types text and integer cannot be matched

Comment: ah, I doubt then it was possibly at all - not sure if there is `operator text = integer`. anyway to compare you need `coalesce(text_colun,int_column::text,'null') = 'null'`

Answer (score 2):

No but you can use a.unitnum = b.unitnum or (a.unitnum is null and b.unitnum is null)

Comment: Attention! `null or false` returns `null`; `null or true` returns `true`.

Comment: You should also know that `null and true` returns `null`; `null and false` returns `false`.

Answer (score 2):

```
IF(a.unitnum IS null AND b.unitnum IS null)
THEN
   RAISE NOTICE 'unitum field is null in both a and b tables'
ELSE
   RAISE NOTICE 'unitum field is not null in at least one a or b tables'
END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to handle all cases:

```
a.unitnum is null        b.unitnum is null
a.unitnum is null        b.unitnum is not null
a.unitnum is not null    b.unitnum is null
a.unitnum is not null    b.unitnum is not null
```

Then you may want to use this expression:

```
select * 
from a, b
where 
((a.unitnum is not null) and (b.unitnum is not null) and (a.unitnum = b.unitnum)) or
((a.unitnum is null) and (b.unitnum is null));
```

Here you can test how it works:

```
SELECT 
  ((a is not null) and (b is not null) and (a = b)) or
  ((a is null) and (b is null))
FROM (VALUES (null,null)
           , (null,1)
           , (1,null)
           , (1,1)
           , (1,2)
       ) t1 (a, b);
```

[image: query result]

P.S.
Just use `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` from the accepted answer... It works the same but shorter.